# Product Catalog Search By Category Id

Tags: magento2, template

How to catalog search by category id?

Magento 2.x

PHP 7.x

Comment: Magento 2 require minimum 3 characters to use catalog search, so we need to pass the query string for 'q=' with minimum 3 characters, so it will not search only using category ID

Comment: Ok, Thanks. It means drawback of Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work it by creating one dropdown like below in the search form:

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
    <option value="3">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="4">Cat 2</option>
    <option value="5">Cat 3</option>
</select>
```

Then url will be like this:

> http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=aaa&cat=3

Comment: Product search while category id and name in text field. If I select any category in the drop-down and text field blank product does not search redirect to the same page.

Comment: It will redirect you to the catalog search result page. What do you want?

Comment: I want to search by the only category without text filed.

Comment: Then what do you want to search? Product then where do you type the product name?

Comment: Please check the link - https://ibb.co/cr9o18